# Generate all permutations of 128bits as bytes or bits, not as strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, permutation

I was trying to generate all the permutations of 128 bits and store them in some kind of structure. I found some useful information about it in other Stack Overflow questions using:

```
keys = map(''.join,itertools.product('01',repeat=n))
```

The problem is that this solution is useful only for enough small values of `n` since it stores the values in a list as strings and therefore each bit in the sequence will be a byte, meaning that each permutation would be 128 bytes long

With such a high value like `n=128`, storing all the permutations as strings is not possible. (My computer runs out of memory when executing `itertools.product()` with `n=128`). Whereas storing the permutations as raw bytes would mean having 16 bytes for each permutation.

My question is how to archive the same results as `intertools.product` but dealing with bytes.

Comment: `map` in Python-3.x does not store the values in a `list`. Besides `2**128` elements is many enough to break your system, regardless of how they are stored. Even if every permutation were only a single bit, you'd need more than `10**25 Terabyte`.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible to do what you ask, however you shouldn't be running out of memory unless you're trying have all the permutations in memory at once (by using something like `list(keys)`. This is because [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns an ***iterator*** object. If you just iterate through it with something like `for value in keys:` then only one (128 character string) will be create at a time.

Comment: @martineau You might not run out of space then, but you'll surely run out of time =)

Comment: @schwobaseggl: Good point. Unless they have a really, really, really fast computer... `;¬)`

Comment: victor: Just out of curiosity, what are you planning on doing with all these permutations?

Comment: hahahaha now I really see that my question was quite silly.

Comment: @martineau It is part of a criptography project in college. We have to decode an encrypted file with AES knowing how the key was generated. So basically each permutation it is a possible key for AES. The number of permutations that can decrypt the file are reduced compared to all the possibilities.

Comment: victor: Ah, I see. Well I don't think you're going to be able to brute-force it...unless of course you have a NSA super-computer available.

Comment: What about if n was 16 instead of 128?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
perms = [ x for x in range(0, 2**128)]
```

Comment: Or better, don't!

Comment: Seriously doubt there'll be enough computer memory to store the 340,282,366,920,938,463,463,374,607,431,768,211,456 elements in the resulting list.